# i want to count charactes in an array of words in java

Tags: java

I need to split a sentence that the user types into equally lines of 20 max characters and replace spaces with dots. What im doing now is splitting the sentence to words. What im thinking is to count the chars of each word. Does anyone know how to count the chars of an array?

```
public class nouratsos {

            public static void main (String args[] ) {

                String text = "";
                int width = 0;
                char c;
                int total = 0;

            System.out.print ("Write the width : ");
                width = BIO.getInt();

                System.out.print ("Enter a text : ");
                text = BIO.getString();


                String[] splitSentence =  text.split("\\s+");


                    for (int i = 0; i < splitSentence.length; i++){

                        System.out.print(splitSentence[i]);
                        System.out.println();




                        }
            }
}
```

Comment: Did you know that the number of chars in a string is equal to the length of the string ? Can be useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I get what you meant, but if you want to know the number of chars per array item, that'd be the length of the string that this item is, so `splitSentence[i].length()` should do the trick.